# Disable hover on HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have building a pie chart using HighCharts library, and here is my chart:

```
 // http://jsfiddle.net/t2MxW/20890/

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        colors: ['#0072BC', '#BFDAFF', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'],
        credits: { enabled: false },
        chart: {
               renderTo: 'container',
               backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
               type: 'pie',
               margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
               spacingTop: 0,
               spacingBottom: 0,
               spacingLeft: 0,
               spacingRight: 0
        },
        title: { text: null },
        plotOptions: {
               pie: {
                   allowPointSelect: false,
                   size: '100%',
                    dataLabels: { enabled: false }
               }
       },
       series: [{
               showInLegend: false,
               type: 'pie',
               name: 'Pie Chart',
               data: [
                     ['Mobile', 65], // first half of pie
                     ['Other', 35] // second half of pie
               ]
       }]
    });
```

But the problem is that I don't want appearing tooltip on mouse over...

Is it possible to disable tooltip on hover?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You need to set the `tooltip` attribute to `false`, like so:

```
tooltip: { enabled: false },
```

**[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/t2MxW/21135/)**

---

Here's the full code for your case:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
       colors: ['#0072BC', '#BFDAFF', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'],
       credits: { enabled: false },
       tooltip: { enabled: false },
       chart: {
              renderTo: 'container',
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
              type: 'pie',
              margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              spacingTop: 0,
              spacingBottom: 0,
              spacingLeft: 0,
              spacingRight: 0
       },
       title: { text: null },
       plotOptions: {
              pie: {
                  allowPointSelect: false,
                  size: '100%',
                   dataLabels: { enabled: false }
              }
      },
      series: [{
              showInLegend: false,
              type: 'pie',
              name: 'Pie Chart',
              data: [
                    ['Mobile', 65], // first half of pie
                    ['Other', 35] // second half of pie
              ]
      }]
});
```

Comment: Sorry I've changed my link to jsFiddle because it was wrong... I have pie chart and this code seems to be not working there - could you please look on it again?

Comment: @Vytalyi Updated, check my new jsFiddle.

Comment: Please notice that your jsFiddle is not working. But great answer though. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! They'd changed the link for the plugin

Comment: What about when I want the tooltip to be enabled at the beginning of the running of the script and then disabled externally with a javascript later? How can I do this?

Answer (score 87):

Disabling tooltip just disables the tooltip but the hover effect is still present.  To disable the hover effect, add the following to your plotOptions:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: when i had a piechart, this made my chart nothing on hover. great answer, the other tooltip enabled false still made my chart hoverable..

Answer (score 36):

You might alternatively want to disable all mouse tracking in general, both tooltip and hover effects:

(copy and paste link) http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.enableMouseTracking

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-enablemousetracking-false/

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems like the more performant way to disable hover effects.

Comment: Thank you! just what I looked for.

Answer (score 16):

The title of the question is about disabling hovering, so in case anyone else finds themselves here for that purpose, I'll elaborate on @SergeyB's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30245693/6157047).

There are a few options that affect how mouse hovering changes a series' styling. They each have different effects depending on the series type. I'll talk about line and pie series here, but generally, you can look under `plotOptions.<seriesType>.states.hover` for styling applied to the currently hovered series and `plotOptions.<seriesType>.states.inactive` for styling applied to the non-hovered series (e.g. plotOptions.pie.states.hover). None of these options affect the tooltip styling.

#### plotOptions.series.states.inactive

[plotOptions.series.states.inactive](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.states.inactive) affects the styling applied to all series that aren't currently being hovered over. To prevent them from fading into the background, set `plotOptions.series.states.inactive.opacity` to 1.

```
var chartOptions = {
    // ...
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            states: {
                inactive: {
                    opacity: 1,
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

[jsFiddle for line](https://jsfiddle.net/galenlong/ghczw61a/)

[jsFiddle for pie](https://jsfiddle.net/galenlong/x0Ld4qa8/)

#### plotOptions.series.states.hover

[plotOptions.series.states.hover](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.states.hover) affects the styling applied to the series that's being hovered over. For example, for a line series, the default is to thicken the line width and apply a halo to the nearest point.

To disable any styling of a currently hovered **line** series, set `plotOptions.series.states.hover.enabled` to false.

```
var chartOptions = {
    // ...
    chart: {
        type: "line",
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false,
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/galenlong/jnxq538h/)

Unfortunately, if we set this on a **pie** series, this will make the hovered slice fade into the background with the rest of the inactive slices (see this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-states-hover-enabled-pie/) for an example). If we want to remove all hover styling without affecting the inactive styling, we can set `plotOptions.series.states.hover.halo.size` to 0 (which removes the halo) and `plotOptions.pie.states.hover.brightness` to 0 (which removes the brightening effect). Note that since brightness is specific to pie series, it's documented under plotOptions.*pie* instead of plotOptions.*series* (though it worked for me even when I added it under plotOptions.series).

```
var chartOptions = {
    // ...
    chart: {
        type: "pie",
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                    halo: {
                        size: 0,
                    },
                    // this worked for me even though it's not
                    // documented under plotOptions.series:
                    //brightness: 0,
                },
            },
        },
        pie: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                    brightness: 0,
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/galenlong/9jtx8f3v/)

#### plotOptions.series.stickyTracking

If you're using a line or area series, you may have noticed that as soon as you hover over the chart, even if you're not touching a series, the nearest series will receive hover styling and the rest will receive inactive styling. This is because [plotOptions.series.stickyTracking](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.stickyTracking) is true by default for line and area series. If you set `plotOptions.series.stickyTracking` to false, hover and inactive styling will only be applied while you're hovering over a line.

```
var chartOptions = {
    // ...
    chart: {
        type: "line",
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stickyTracking: false,
        },
    },
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-stickytracking-false/)

#### plotOptions.series.enableMouseTracking

As @ninedozen [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35050263/6157047), you can completely disable all responsive interactions based on mouse movement by setting `plotOptions.series.enableMouseTracking` to false. Note that this will also disable tooltips in addition to hover/inactive styling.

#### Options scope

To apply these options to all series in the entire chart, place them under `plotOptions.series`. To apply them only to certain series types (or if the option is specific to a certain series), place them under `plotOptions.<seriesType>`. To apply them to a specific series, place them inside that series' options.

```
var chartOptions = {
    series: [
        {
            name: "series1",
            type: "line",
            data: [...],
            // these options will only apply to series1, not series2 or series3
            states: {...},
        },
        {
            name: "series2",
            type: "line"
            data: [...],
        },
        {
            name: "series3",
            type: "pie"
            data: [...],
        }
    ],
    plotOptions: {
        // these options will apply to all series in the chart
        series: {states: {...}},
        // these options will only apply to series of type line
        // i.e. series1 and series2
        line: {states: {...}}
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped to remove the hover effect completely.

Comment: My problem was with the inactive state apparently, thanks!

Comment: how would I remove the hover tooltip but keep the chart clickable?

Comment: I find reducing the opacity to around 0.7 or 0.8 improves usability. The fading is too much otherwise as the lines almost disappear.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply turn them of using the following:

```
tooltip: {
    enabled: false       
},
```

Answer (score 5):

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    states: {
      inactive: {
        opacity: 1,
      },
    },
  }
}
```

I did this to display multiple line charts on hover.

Comment: This is the only answer that helped me

Answer (score 4):

In order to completely turn off tooltip and hover effects on a chart,
it is needed to turn off the tooltip, disable hover state and set inactive data opacity to 100%.

This answer is based on previous answers and shows a complete solution to the problem.

This is the configuration which turns off the hover and tooltip effects:

```
  series: {
    states: {
      hover: {
        enabled: false
      },
      inactive: {
        opacity: 1,
      }
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply disable it by setting the option

```
tooltip:{
   enabled: false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually just disable the style in css so I can still access the hover event in JS if needed...

```
.highcharts-tooltip {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: tooltip: { enabled: false } does not work for me (v5), this one worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the accepted answer, you need to set

```
 tooltip: { enabled: false }
```

**Note** - you must specify this as a property of your `Highcharts.Options` object (i.e. your chart options object, *not* a property of your series). So, either specify it in the JSON that you pass into your `Highcharts.Chart` object, or specify it as a property of a `Highcharts.Options` object that you *explicitly* create, before you pass it to you `Highcharts.Chart`

See https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.enabled