# disable hover on special slice of pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I know how to [disable hover on highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231565/disable-hover-on-highcharts), and I edit the answer to disable hove on special slice as this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyakout91/e7brd9do/), but it doesn't work.

I edit series attribute as the following:

```
series: [{
  showInLegend: false,
  type: 'pie',
  name: 'Pie Chart',
  data: [
    ['Mobile', 65], // first half of pie
    {
       name: 'Other', 
       y: 35, 
       tooltip: { enabled: false }
    } // second half of pie
  ]
```

How can I disable hover for special slices on pie charts using highcharts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close with your custom tooltip property idea. I personally rather using custom names as well, therefor instead of adding a `tooltip` data object, i'd use a custom property named `tooltipDisabled`:

```
{name: 'Other', y: 35, tooltipDisabled:true} // second half of pie
```

And then, using a tooltip `formatter` function (a callback function called when a point is hoverd, which is totally override-able), I'd discriminate the points with this property:

```
    tooltip: {
        useHTML:true,
        formatter: function(){
            return this.point.tooltipDisabled ? false : this.point.name +"<br><span style='font-size:18px;vertical-align:middle'>&#8226;</span>"+this.series.name+": <b>"+this.y+"</b>";
        }
```

returning `false`, as you have probably guessed, disables the tooltip.
(as you can see I also added `useHTML:true`, so highcharts renders the bullet next to the point name.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e7brd9do/2/