# Highcharts - disable hover for slices on pie chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, pie-chart

I have a pie chart on which I would like to disable hover only on some of the slices.

So far, the best I could do is in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cp2tL9sd/). By triggering an error (the plap function does not exists), I can prevent the hover action. However, this is not clean and if someday I create a plap function that might break my code.

I have tried using setState, but could not make it work. I think the plotOptions.series.states.hover.enabled options is stronger than the series.point.state.

So my question is how can I achieve what I want without being too dirty ?

RQ: I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341761/disable-hover-on-special-slice-of-pie-chart) but it does not do what I want.

RQ2: stackoverflow asks for some code so here is the chart options I use to make it work

```
chart: {type: 'pie'},
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
          states: {hover: {enabled: true}},
      }
    },
    series: [{
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function() {
            if (this.y < 100) {
              plap();
            }
          },
        }
      },
      data: [89.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0]
    }],
    tooltip: {enabled: false},
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "being too dirty"?

Comment: well this code raises "Uncaught ReferenceError: plap is not defined".This is the opposite of clean to me. It pollutes my console and the risk of it breaking in the future without any notice is high.

Comment: use something like chart.series[0].data.......

Comment: Could you provide a working jsfiddle ? I don't quite understand your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, a little dirty, is setting point's state to hover on mouseOver event. setState('hover') will do nothing with the point if it is already in hover state.

```
mouseOver: function() {
        if (this.y < 100) {
   //       plap();
                this.state = 'hover';
        }
      }
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cp2tL9sd/4/

Comment: it works but I dont understand well why ? Here setting the state to hover actually disable hover how can this be ?

Comment: It is a consequence of how setState() is implemented. If the point is in some state, setState() method, before does something, checks if the point's actual state is different than a 'to be state'. If they are equal, setState() will do nothing - because it assumes that the point's graphic is already updated.